# How I can launch a group of Thread in Java Code

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question.

I have 10000 strings and I want to perform some operation on each of them. I would like to parallelize this operations in order to make the total execution time acceptable.

I decided to create the thread. In particular, every 10 strings I launch 10 threads. For every threads I save the result in a list.

I have tried two versions of my code. This is my first version.

```
int size = 10000;
int cont = 0;
        int n = 1;
        String[] arrstr2;
        int threadgroup = 10;
if (cont + threadgroup - 1 > size) {
                        arrstr2[i - cont] = subject.toString();
                    } else {
                        arrstr2[i - cont] = subject.toString();
                    }

                    if ((i == (threadgroup * n) - 1) || (i == size - 1)) {

                        cont = i + 1;
                        n = n + 1;
                        for (int j = 0; j < arrstr2.length; j++) {
                            Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread(arrstr2[j], l));
                            t.start();

                            try {
                                t.join();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if (cont + threadgroup - 1 > size) {
                            arrstr2 = new String[size - i - 1];
                        }
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
```

In this version I don't get an advantages in the total execution.

This is my second version:

```
    int size = 10000;
    int cont = 0;
            int n = 1;
            String[] arrstr2;
            int threadgroup = 10;
    if (cont + threadgroup - 1 > size) {
                            arrstr2[i - cont] = subject.toString();
                        } else {
                            arrstr2[i - cont] = subject.toString();
                        }

                        if ((i == (threadgroup * n) - 1) || (i == size - 1)) {

                            cont = i + 1;
                            n = n + 1;
                            for (int j = 0; j < arrstr2.length; j++) {
                                Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread(arrstr2[j], l));
                                t.start();

                            }
try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (cont + threadgroup - 1 > size) {
                                arrstr2 = new String[size - i - 1];
                            }
                        }
                        i = i + 1;
```

In this case I lose some information.
MyThread is a class that does some processing and puts the result in a list java:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{

    String subject;
    private List<String[]> l;

    public MyThread(String subject, List<String[]> l) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.l = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (l){
        //do something
        String[] result = new String[2];
        result[0] = res0;
        result[1] = res1;
        l.add(result);
    }
}
```

For my goal, this code is correct? How can I launch a group of thread in Java Code and to retrieve an acceptable time?

Comment: Use an ExecutorService with a fixed Thread pool! :)

Comment: Can you do an example for me?

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: you can also cut down all of the above to ONE SINGLE LINE OF CODE with streams.

Comment: @specializt: can you do an example?

Comment: yes, i can. Im guessing you were asking if i WILL do one .... well : yourStringCollection.parallelStream().forEach(oneString -> doSomething(oneString));

Comment: reduction : 
String joined = yourStringCollection.parallelStream().reduce("", (accumulated, current) -> accumulated + ", " + current);

Comment: mapping / data-retrieval in objects :
List<Something> someList = yourObjectCollection.parallelStream().map(obj -> obj.getSomething()).collect(Collectors.toList());

and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little example with an `ExecutorService`. The thread size is fixed to 10, but your can adjust it to your needs.

The `StringTask` basically reverses the given string.

```
public class Test {

    private static final int THREADS = 10;
    private static final int DATA_SIZE = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare a new ExecutorService with a maximum of 2 threads.
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

        // Prepare a list of Future results.
        List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>(DATA_SIZE);

        // Submit the tasks and store the results.
        for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {
            futures.add(service.submit(new StringTask("Sample String " + i)));
        }

        // Accept no new tasks.
        service.shutdown();

        // Retrieve the actual String results.
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(DATA_SIZE);
        try {
            for (Future<String> future : futures) {
                // The get() method blocks if the execution of the task is not finished.
                results.add(future.get());
                System.out.println(future.get());
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
            System.out.println("Error while getting result!");
            ee.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Error while getting result!");
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callable task that reverses a given String.
     */
    private static final class StringTask implements Callable<String> {
        private String input;

        private StringTask(String input) {
            super();

            if (input == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }

            this.input = input;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = this.input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                builder.append(this.input.charAt(i));
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I use a `Callable` here instead of a `Runnable` because the `Callable` allows the task to actually return a result that we can use (through the `Future` interface). If you only need a task executed, you can simply use a `Runnable`!

Comment: This solution is good, but in my case, I get an error. The operation that my thread have to do is primarily concerned with the execution of a SPARQL query (which for brevity I omitted before). In particular I have QueryExecution exec1 = querymy(stringa, stringa1);
            ResultSet results1 = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(exec1.execSelect()); 
I have seen that the threads are correctly launched, but when I retreive the results,

Comment: I get this error:
Error while getting result!
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: HttpException: 503
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188). In particular, I get this error in this for cycle: for (Future<String> future : futures) {
                // The get() method blocks if the execution of the task is not finished.
                results.add(future.get());
                System.out.println(future.get());
            }

Comment: @Musich87 The [ExecutionException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) doc says that this exception is _thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted by throwing an exception._ Does the execution of you SPARQL query throw an exception? Maybe the `Throwable.getCause()` can help you on this.

Comment: No, I get the error when I execute the function "get" on futures list. In fact, there is a catch (ExecutionException ee) for this istruction. I'm retrieving only the information, why I get this error? In first cycle, I don't get error

Comment: @Musich87 The `ExecutionException: HttpException: 503` makes me suspect that once your server-side service accepts the first task, it blocks for any other incoming tasks. Can you try with a `DATA_SIZE` of 1 and then 2 to test this out? (See [Http 503](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) as an additional reference)

Comment: I have tried. I get results until to my first 40/50 strings. This number is very variable. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @Musich87 I don't know, it looks to me that your database or datasource is getting overloaded after a certain number of requests or tasks. Try to test your datasource for multithreaded requests to scope its limits, or try simply using less threads in your Thread pool.

Comment: Ok, I have decrease the THREAD_NUMBER (=3) and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might take a look at the new Java 8 Stream API.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html
There you can easily parallelize such operations.

Comment: indeed, streams surely are far more sophisticated (and less error-prone) than everything inexperienced people are able to create.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8:

```
List<String> res = Arrays.toStream(arrstr2)
                         .parallel()
                         .map(s -> doWork(s))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Where can I download Java 8 EE for 64bit?

Comment: Here: https://www.google.com/search?q=jdk8 But maybe you should stick to java 7 and use an ExecutorService as Alexis Leclerc suggested.